# Android RadioGroup/RadioButton NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, radio-group

Hello I'm starting at Android Development and I need to do a user registration in two tables at the same time.
I have the User table and I have Patient and Caregiver tables, in the Register Activity I have two radio buttons to check the user type. If "Patient" is selected then I want to insert into user and patient.
But, my radiogroup (i think) is always returning null. I have checked other posts and tried different solutions but neither of them worked.

So my **RegisterActivity** code:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

private AlphaAnimation buttonClick = new AlphaAnimation(0.0F, 0.8F);
//RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3;
RadioGroup radiogroup;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    //rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    //rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);

}

 //get selected radio button id (also returns null)
 /* public int getIDRadio() {
    int idRadio = radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    if (idRadio == R.id.radioButton) {
        return 1; //patient
    } else if (idRadio == R.id.radioButton2) {


    return 2; //caregiver
    } else {
        return -1; //erro não esta nenhum selecionado
    }
  }*/

//another try
public boolean radioGroup(){
    int checkedID = radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId(); //LINE 51
    if(checkedID == R.id.radioButton) {
        return true; //for patient
    } else {
        return false; //for caregiver
    }
    //return radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radioButton;
}


public void onRegisterClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.REGISTARBUTTON) {

    EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFNAME);
    EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFEMAIL);
    EditText uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFUNAME);
    EditText password1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFPASSWORD1);
    EditText password2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFPASSWORD2);

    String namestr = name.getText().toString();
    String emailstr = email.getText().toString();
    String unamestr = uname.getText().toString();
    String pass1str = password1.getText().toString();
    String pass2str = password2.getText().toString();

        if (namestr.isEmpty() || emailstr.isEmpty() || unamestr.isEmpty() || pass1str.isEmpty()) { //se os campos estiverem null
           Toast fields = Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Por favor, preencha os campos!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           fields.show();
       } else if (!pass1str.equals(pass2str)) { //se as passwords não forem iguais
           Toast pass = Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Password incorrecta, tente de novo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           pass.show();
     /*} else if (getIDRadio() == -1) { //se nenhum radiobutton estiver selecionado
           Toast userType = Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Por favor, selecione um tipo de utilizador!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           userType.show();*/

     } else {

        if (radioGroup()) {
         //if patient radiobutton selected inserts into user and patient tables
            UsersRegister userPatient = new UsersRegister();
            userPatient.setName(namestr);
            userPatient.setEmail(emailstr);
            userPatient.setUname(unamestr);
            userPatient.setPassword(pass1str); //pass1 ou pass2 e igual

            Patient patient = new Patient();
            patient.setName(namestr);
            patient.setEmail(emailstr);
            patient.setPassword(pass1str);

            helper.insertUser(userPatient); //LINE 103

} else { //inserts into user and caregiver tables (...)
```

Now my **RegisterActivity Layout**:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup">


    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Paciente"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cuidador"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>


</RadioGroup>
```

**Logcat**

```
Process: com.example.dc.smoveen, PID: 25361
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3848)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3843)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.dc.smoveen.RegisterActivity.radioGroup(RegisterActivity.java:51)
            at com.example.dc.smoveen.DatabaseHelper.insertUser(DatabaseHelper.java:108)
            at com.example.dc.smoveen.RegisterActivity.onRegisterClick(RegisterActivity.java:103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3843)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So since it always returns null giving the NullPointerException error I can't do the signup.

Can anyone help me discover what have I done wrong?

Comment: Show your logcat error

Comment: Stack trace would be useful.

Comment: @RajeshJadav  updated the post with the logcat error

Comment: Counting the lines till is seems there is a problem with you editTexts, could you please add the layout were your textfields are declared?

Comment: @jrsall92 what's the problem you see? I did the sign up only in the User  table before with the same editTexts and it worked, I havent changed that...

Comment: @PatríciaGarcia in your stack trace the problem in your code occurs in lines 51 and 103. I counted till 53 but without numbered lines I may have made a mistake but I, that's the area of your early declarations in your `orRegisterClick(...)` method. Have a look in those lines.

Comment: @jrsall92 I've updated the RegisterActivity code and added comment in the lines where the error occurs, can you check it please?

Comment: @PatríciaGarcia have you also update the logcat from after you commended those lines? Also you seem to have commented the closing bracket at the start of the first commented out line.

Comment: @PatríciaGarcia I have run your code it's working, so I think you must check `radiogroup ` variable it may be null, make sure `radiogroup` is present in `activity_register.xml`

Comment: @PatríciaGarcia do you call radioGroup() from DatabaseHelper?

Comment: @schopy no radioGroup() is defined in RegisterActivity. I call radioGroup() in DatabaseHelper to know each of the radiobutton is selected

Comment: @jrsall92 no i didn't update the logcat, its the same...

Comment: @JaiSoni how is my code running for you and not for meee?! radiogroup is the id of the <RadioGroup...> in the activity_register.xml so it is present. Why is the variable null?

Comment: Can you post the code when you call `radioGroup()` from `DatabaseHelper`? I think this call is the origin of the NPE, maybe you're not using the same insance of the Activity.

Comment: @PatríciaGarcia I have called it in activity, I think Rami is correct may be this happens because you are calling it in `DatabaseHelper`.. post some code `DatabaseHelper` where you are calling `radioGroup()`

Comment: @PatríciaGarcia Also from your code I have notice that it is working for first time ` if (radioGroup())` in side `onRegisterClick()`, then at line 103 you called `insertUser()` of `DatabaseHelper` which again call `radioGroup()` this time you get NPE, so it's problem in calling `radioGroup()` from `insertUser()`

Comment: @Rami in fact the problem really was in the DatabaseHelper and finally i've solved it and i already can insert into the two tables! Thank you so much for all the help!!

Comment: @JaiSoni in fact the problem really was in the DatabaseHelper and finally i've solved it and i already can insert into the two tables! Thank you so much for all the help!!